# Consistency in Laravel localization

Tags: laravel, localization, consistency

I have a laravel appication that I am building. I am building a multi language application which would have french and spanish and its url would be

```
www.example.com/fr/route/slug for french 
www.example.com/es/route/slug for spanish 
www.example.com/route/slug for english which is the main one
```

But I am very confused as to how I should go about maintaining the consistency from one url to another within the same language i.e. when I click on a link which is under french, what should be returned should still be french. e.g:

```
from 
www.example.com/fr/route/slug1  to 
www.example.com/fr/route/another_path to
www.example.com/fr/route/final_path which would be maintaing same language path

www.example.com/es/route/slug1 to 
www.example.com/es/route/another_path to
www.example.com/es/route/final_path for spanish 

www.example.com/route/slug1 to 
www.example.com/route/another_path to 
www.example.com/route/final_path for english
```

Also when I change from e.g. french to english the page must be consistent e.g.

```
www.example.com/fr/route/slug1 to 
www.example.com/fr/route/another_path in french to english
www.example.com/route/another_path
```

What are the steps I should take? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly recommend [Laravel Localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) package which takes care of all of that and more.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this group for all your route

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => 'web', 'prefix' => '{local}'], function () {
```

and then make middleware where you catch the local and then :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    App::setLocale($locale);
}
```

And apply it by adding it in your $middleware array located in the Http/kernel.php file

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please how should that be done. What are the steps I must take. I know that I would add the language directory to app.php, but what other things would have to do to get all that you have stated above

Answer (score 0):

To maintain this you can follow the below steps :

1. At change point of language at your website ( eg. Change language from dropdown ) , store selected value in session and then your page should be reload
2. Then you have to create one middelware to manage the localization.
3. You just have to simply write few line of code in handle method of the Middleware.

   $lang = Session::get("language");
   App::setLocale($lang);
4. Thats it, this will manage your consistency.

Comment: thank your very much. Please how would I get this done. Please can u explain a little more. I am a little confused about what u just said.